When firebase push notification come then the app is runing in the background
When firebase push notification come from the terminate state then the app is runing in the background. If i remove AudioServiceActivity from manifest then this problem not arrise
I need firebase default behavior when firebase push notification is come i want my apps donot run in the background untill i tap notification

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
